# How to set flexible number of rows in textarea in Bootstrap?

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4

I am using `textarea` where we can type whatever we want, using **Bootstrap**.
But, it's height is set to 3 **rows** by default. I wanna make it flexible. As the user goes beyond 3 rows, I want the text area to expand. Instead a **scroll** **bar** appears. I know, the text area is responsive, the user can drag and resize it. But, I a, going to add a print option where the user can get a pdf of what they have typed. So, the limited row feature is a hindrance.

Here is my code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
        integrity="sha384-F3w7mX95PdgyTmZZMECAngseQB83DfGTowi0iMjiWaeVhAn4FJkqJByhZMI3AhiU" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <title>Index</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="container row text-center">
            <div class="container col bg-primary text-light"><span style="font-size: 5rem;">S</span></div>
        </div>
        <div class="container row text-center">
            <div class="container col bg-primary text-light"><span style="font-size: 2rem;">STRENGTHS</span></div>
        </div>
        <div class="container row text-center">
            <div class="container col bg-primary text-light"><span style="font-size: 2rem;">
                    <form>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <textarea class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlTextarea1" rows="3"></textarea>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </span></div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.9.3/dist/umd/popper.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-W8fXfP3gkOKtndU4JGtKDvXbO53Wy8SZCQHczT5FMiiqmQfUpWbYdTil/SxwZgAN"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.1/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-skAcpIdS7UcVUC05LJ9Dxay8AXcDYfBJqt1CJ85S/CFujBsIzCIv+l9liuYLaMQ/"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: add JQuery code exactly before **</body>** like: ``<script>$(document).ready(function () {
    $('textarea').on('input', function () { 
        this.style.height = 'auto'; 
        this.style.height = (this.scrollHeight) + 'px'; 
    });
});</script>``

Comment: hey it did worked!!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that's what you need:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('textarea').on('input', function () { 
        this.style.height = 'auto'; 
        this.style.height = (this.scrollHeight) + 'px'; 
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea autocomplete="off" style="resize:none; overflow:hidden;"></textarea>
```

Comment: You must add a working example using a Stack Snippet

Comment: where do I have to add the js part?

Comment: you can add it to the body or you can make a new file.js and call the file from the head of your html, like: ``<script src="Path/file.js"></script>``

Comment: I did that but it is not working.
Can you please add the code in my snippet?

Comment: did you add jquery ? can I see your scripts please !?

Comment: I had a doubt although, is it necessary to insert this line <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script> before the textarea or can we put it anywhere?